# Mot pour ce qui se trouve à coté d'ici

Tags: demande-de-mot

Si dans un texte je veux référer à quelque chose qui se trouve plus haut, j'utilise "ci-dessus". Si c'est plus bas, j’écris "ci-dessous'.

Existe-t-il un mot similaire pour quelque chose qui se trouve à coté de l'endroit? J'essayerais "ci-coté", mais j'ai mes doutes si ce mot existe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oui il existe un mot, c'est "[ci-contre](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ci-contre)".

Dans la [série](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/juridi/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_s&page=9EOLbIPV7G7A.html), on a aussi "ci-joint" pour un document joint à une lettre ou un e-mail.

Answer (score 2):

Pour un lieu ou une partie de la mise en page il est préféré d'utiliser "ci-contre".

Exemple :
"L'image ci-contre." = L'image se trouvant à côté du texte en question.

Dans une phrase, suivant l'endroit où la partie à laquelle nous faisons référence se situe après, il est utilisé "ci-après", tandis que si cela se trouve avant, il arrive communément d'utiliser "précédemment". Tout du moins est ce que je vois habituellement.

Exemple :
"Comme expliqué précédemment vous pourrez trouver ci-après une case afin d'écrire vos notes." = Une partie du texte que vous avez déjà lue vous expliquait qu'il se trouve une case plus loin qui vous permet d'y écrire quelque chose.